# Setting State in a Callback inside of componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm currently using React 16.3(React Native), written [here](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/29/react-v-16-3.html), it suggests that I *SHOULD* be making any async requests inside of componentDidMount instead of componentWillMount because that will soon be deprecated.

Unfortunately I'm getting a no-op warning as I'm trying to fetch data inside of componentDidMount, setting the data returned from my axios request as my state.

Here's a snippet —

```
export default class MyComponent extends Component {
    state = {
      myData: []
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      axios.get('api-endpoint')
      .then(res => this.setState({ myData: res.data })
    }
    render() { return <View>...</View> }
}
```

and the warning —

```
Warning: Can only update a mounted or mounting component. 
This usually means you called setState, replaceState, or 
forceUpdate on an unmounted component. This is a no-op.

Please check the code for the MyComponent component.
```

Comment: What is the full text of the warning you get?

Comment: @AliAnkarali the warning is the last snippet

Comment: It seems your component is unmounted before the response is returned. You can abort the response in componentWillUnmount

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the problem of having asynchronous code in your components. When for example Promise resolves (might take few seconds), a user may have already navigated to another part of your application, so when Promise resolves and tries to execute `setState` - you get the error that you try to update unmounted component.

My suggestion is to use something like redux-thunk, redux-saga or redux-observable etc. for your asynchronous logic... However, you can do a simple check - **but it is an antipattern** :

```
export default class MyComponent extends Component {
    state = {
      myData: []
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      this.isMounted = true;

      axios.get('api-endpoint')
      .then(res => {
        if(this.isMounted) {
          this.setState({ myData: res.data })
        }
      })
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
      this.isMounted = false;
    }
    render() { return <div>...</div> }
}
```

Comment: I understand that setting state when a component is unmounted is a no-op — unfortunately I only have one Scene in my react native application, nothing ever gets unmounted at any point of the rendering. I just don't understand why it suggests that I should be fetching data inside of didMount if I can't set states in the callback. Also, Thanks for the reply!

Comment: try to put console log in `componentWillMount` to see if it's not getting called. componentDidMount is a good place to **start** asynchronous logic, but you need to watch out for callbacks.

Comment: So when I logged something in componentWillUnmount, it _does_ get called. So I think that there's something unmounting my component higher in the tree. I don't think that using the redux-thunk solution is the best route if it's an antipattern, so I will try to figure something out. Thank you so much for you help!

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to follow proper Flux. You can attach a store listener for your `MyComponent` in `componentDidMount()` as follows.

```
componentDidMount() {
   //call async data fecthing method here
   store.addListener('eventname', onDataReceipt);
}
```

Before this, you can move the state change logic to `onDataReceipt` method. Call the async Data fetch from `componentDidMount()` and `dispatch` an action for which a store has registered to. Then emit the event from store. Since you have already subscribed to the event in `componentDidMount()`, on event emission `onDataReceipt()` would be executed.
Also dont forget to remove the listener in `componentWillUnMout()`

```
componentWillUnMount() {
   store.removeListener('eventname', onDataReceipt);
}
```

Flux would take care of the rest And you wouldn' thave to worry about the warning.

Answer (score 1):

Update — The reason why my component was getting unmounted because I was setting state in my parent component. When setting state in the parent component, it forced a re-rendering of the component, which trickled down the tree & dismounted in the middle of my asynchronous request.