# React js, print out react component's state is not empty, but when call this.state, all data gone

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the React component's componentDidMount() I make an axios get request to receive a response and setState to the component. The response is correct, and when print out the component object in the component class with `this`, the object looks good. Then I call `console.log(this.state)`, then every property of the component become empty.  Why this happens? How can I get the state's property?

**MyComponent.js**
React component did mount method:

```
    componentDidMount() {

    getLastWeek(this); // here I make a get request

    console.log('===');
    console.log(this); // this line prints out an object will all the properties
    console.log(this.state); // all properties of state disappear
}
```

The get request used above:
**service.js**

```
...
    function getLastWeek(component) {

    const lastWeek = getEndpoint(7);

    Axios.get(lastWeek)
        .then(res => {

            const bpi = res.data.bpi;
            const prices = Object.values(bpi);

            component.setState({ lastWeek: prices });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
}
...
```

Comment: I would stay away from async calls in componentdidmount that set state. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49941991/setting-state-in-a-callback-inside-of-componentdidmount

Answer (score 0):

You are making an axios request which is an asynchronous function, so what is happening is you are using `console.log(this.state)` before the state gets set.

The `render()` method gets executed every time the state changes so if you put your `console.log` inside the `render()` method you should now see how your state change. Something like this:

```
class Example extends Component {
    constructor() {
        ...
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        ...
    }
    render() {
        console.log(this.state);
        return(...);
    }
}
```

Comment: make sense... but why the first `console.log` get the new state while the one after it not? Is it the second `console.log` called before the first one? But in the console it prints after the first log statement